# Vb.net SQL SUM value to a label

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table by name assetcategory in database.I need the sum of quantity attribute where Asset_name attribute equal to CPU. After this i want to store the result in a label.

I wrote the following query but its not working.

```
  Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("Select sum(Quantity) from assetcategory where ID ='A013' and Asset_Name='CPU'", con)     
  Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
  dr1 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
    While dr1.Read
      Label4.text=dr1.item(0).Tostring
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if [sum(Quantity) is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102) because no rows match

Comment: hey..tat particular query is working in sql. But how to store that value in a variable using vb.net

Comment: Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("Select sum(Quantity) from assetcategory where ID ='A013' and Asset_Name='CPU'", con)  
        Dim cpucount As Int32
        cpucount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
        lblcpu.Text = cpucount

Comment: You are getting the Quantity columns for all rows in the assetcategory table with a certain ID and Asset_Name and then summing those values.  There will only be one result.