# When does COUNT(*) return NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello
I have a colleague who always writes `ISNULL(COUNT(*),0)`, but I always thought that `COUNT(*)` could never return `NULL`.

But then I searched the interwebs and my findings allowed me to write this little piece of code:

```
create table t1 (
    val1 varchar(50),
)

select count(*) from t1
where val1 like 'abc'
group by val1
```

Are there any other cases when COUNT(*) returns `NULL`?

Comment: Your sample does not return a NULL for the count. It returns 0 rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result)

Comment: Ok, this may be a bit off the wall, but I found this because my UPDATE x SET y = (SELCT COUNT(*)...) is setting y to null.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't return `NULL`. The `GROUP BY` in your example makes it return no rows at all, which is not the same as a `NULL` in a column.

Comment: Just a note. If you were looking to do this in an update statement, for example: <br><br>

    update t2 set col1=select count(*) from t1
    where val1 like 'abc'
    group by val1

the solution would be to wrap that in an IsNull, like this:

    update t2 set col1=IsNull((select count(*) from t1
    where val1 like 'abc'
    group by val1),0)

Answer (score 2):

That example doesn't return NULL.  It returns no rows at all because of the GROUP BY on an empty set.

COUNT(*) cannot return a NULL.  So the ISNULL is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL it not needed it will return a number