# SQL Return code from Select count(*)

Tags: sql

What is the return code from SQL if you execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) from` ... and a `count` of `0` is returned? Is it `0` or `100` (not found)?

Thank you.

Comment: What dbms are you asking for?

Comment: Are you talking about IBM DB2? If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: What will be the value if it's IBM DB2? Is it 100 or 1?

Answer (score 2):

It will always return 1 row with 1 column (containing the number of rows i.e. the count(*) value), if that is what you are asking....

Comment: SQL return code (or SQLCODE) != result set of `COUNT()` query

Answer (score 0):

Zero because there were no rows. What would 100 have to do with it?

Please look at my answer here too: [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102)

Edit: unless you mean DB2 as noted elsewhere...

Comment: @BoltClock, @squillman: return code is zero. As I said, what does 100 have to do with it? There is no "not found" in SQL generally. Your comments are almost as bad as the question...

Comment: Well yeah given that OP didn't even specify what DBMS... I'm guessing it's IBM DB2. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB2_SQL_return_codes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about MS SQL Server, the @@error code will always be 0 assuming you query a valid table.  The @@error code is describing the success of the action itself, not the success of the results.

Comment: return codes can be set only by RETURN or internal errors. There is no return code for a SELECT COUNT. Do you mean @@ERROR?