# SQL query does not return the correct count

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, ado.net

I am trying to count the number of rows and pass that count value to do some logic. Below is the code:

```
   static public int GetNoImagesofMakeID(int makeID)
{
    string sql = "Select COUNT(*) from makeImages";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count);
}

  protected void hideUnhideFileUpload(int makeID)
{

    int count = caravans.GetNoImagesofMakeID(makeID);
    if (count >= 10)
    {
        FileUpload2.Enabled = false;
    }

    else
    {
        FileUpload2.Enabled = true;
    }

}
```

I don't know for what reason the count is always 1. I checked the same query on SQL Server and it's working fine. But, here dt.rows.count always return 1.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning one row with one value (the count of rows), so `dt.Rows.Count` is correctly returning 1 (meaning 1 row returned by your query).
Using a datatable, you would find the count returned by your query at `dt.Rows[0][0]` (row 0 column 0 of your datatable)

Answer (score 7):

The code is returning the number of rows rather than the result of the COUNT(*).  That SQL statement will always just return a single row.  Rather than filling a data adapter, you can just run the command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = someSQLConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select COUNT(*) from makeImages";
return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: i was using cmd.ExecuteReader() which was always returning 0 even though i was accessing the result like this, var result = reader.GetOrdinal("NUMBER"); the query was "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM table", changing this too cmd.ExecuteScalar() fixed the issue, not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

A count(*) always returns a row, regardless of how many rows it is counting. a count(*) is a scalar value. What you need to do is read the value returned in the recordset.

More information about counts in this question: [SQL Return code from Select count(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809551/sql-return-code-from-select-count/5809612#5809612)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you getting the table row count, instead of the returned value from your count query, as this will return only single row?

```
return Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
```