# Why do I get either zero rows or a row with a NULL value, just by changing the SELECT clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I bumped into something unexpected just now, and it reminded me that there is still much I do not know about SQL.

I have a reporting query which uses `UNION ALL` to concatenate results for different date ranges and store them, in HTML form, in a temp table.  The query gave a NULL value for the MTD range today, as there was no activity on the 1st.  What I don't understand is: why did I get any row at all?  Toying with the query, I see that this snip:

```
SELECT
    70000,
    '<tr>' + dbo.FormatAsHTMLRowHead('Month to date') + '</tr>'
FROM
    #RawResults
WHERE
    Date = '2011-05-01'
```

...gives no results, zero rows, as expected.  However, if I add a field to the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
    70000,
    '<tr>'
    + dbo.FormatAsHTMLRowHead('Month to date')
    + dbo.FormatAsHTMLCell(dbo.FormatInteger(SUM(Leads)), 'R')
    + '</tr>'
FROM
    #RawResults
WHERE
    Date = '2011-05-01'
```

Then I get a single row with a NULL value:

```
Sequence HTML
-------- ----
70000    NULL
```

Querying `SELECT Field FROM #RawResults WHERE Date = '2011-05-01'` returns no results, so it seems that a UDF acting on a non-literal causes SQL to return a row even when there's no matching value in the `WHERE` clause.  Is this some weird edge case, or does this make perfect sense for some reason that escapes me this morning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd one has an aggregate SUM without a GROUP BY = always one row returned

See my answer here: [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102)

Comment: Gotcha, I was distracted by the UDFs but the `SUM()` was the issue.  Thanks!