# Always select a row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `case` statment (see below) but I always want to return a value even if nothing matches the `WHERE` clase. Is that possible? Thanks

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM 
fldt_QueryDSLAM lastDay
WHERE AccountID = @acc
    AND lastDay.DSL = @dsl
GROUP BY lastDay.DSL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the select within an isnull;

```
SELECT ISNULL((
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM 
    fldt_QueryDSLAM lastDay
    WHERE AccountID = @acc
        AND lastDay.DSL = @dsl
    GROUP BY lastDay.DSL
), -99 /*no match*/)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the WHERE clause returns one row (or one group more precisely), remove the GROUP BY. Then you'll always have one row in the output.

I assume it will (return one group) because you have GROUP BY on a filter column, and AccountID isn't mentioned in either SELECT or GROOUP BY

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM 
    fldt_QueryDSLAM lastDay
WHERE
    AccountID = @acc AND lastDay.DSL = @dsl
```

For why, see this: [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102)