# Simplify SQL Query into sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**tblticket**

**id issue status**
1   test   1
2   test   2
3   test   3

i want to find count based on status 1,2,3 and so on

i write 3 sql statment as follows

select count(*) from ticket where status=1
select count(*) from ticket where status=2
select count(*) from ticket where status=3

any way to simplify this into single query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is

```
select count(*), status
from ticket
group by status
```

However, this gives different results if you have no rows for a status because the behaviour documented here: [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102)

Assuming only 3 status values you'd do this:

```
select count(t.status), s.status
from
   (SELECT 1 AS status UNION  ALL SELECT 2 UNION  ALL SELECT 3) s
   LEFT JOIN
   ticket t ON s.status = t.status 
group by
   s.status
```

..or with a separate status lookup table:

```
select  count(t.status), s.status
from
   (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM status) s
   LEFT JOIN
   ticket t ON s.status = t.status 
group by
   s.status
```

Comment: Ha, had me by 0:20! Blast my slow connection :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM tblticket
GROUP BY status
```

If you really only want those three statuses, you could also do:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM tblticket
WHERE status IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY status
```