# Count of DROP Statements Executed for sp_MSforeachtable

Tags: sql-server-2008, drop-table

[image]Am dropping all the table names in DB using

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
```

Is there a way i can get count on number of tables dropped.

Thanks,
Peru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @before int;

SELECT @before = COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables;
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
SELECT @before - COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) - @before FROM sys.tables   returning NULL

Comment: The first SELECT assigns it. It will be zero. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102

Comment: am getting NULL. What does the second SELECT Does ? First returns numeric second SELECT returns NULL

Comment: added screenshot of results to my question

Comment: The 2nd select calculates the difference between before and after. To get NULL you have to have NULL in @before. I've tried this and it works for me

Comment: This will not work accurately if a parallel proccess is also dropping tables... I wonder if is there somenthig like @@ROWCOUNT but for drop statements.