# Group by issue in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I have written a query to display the sum of quantity as follows without group by

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(VUItems.Quantity), 0) AS OrderQty
FROM   VUItems
```

This returns as `0.00` but the same query when using `group by` not displaying `0.00` what might be the problem

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(VUItems.Quantity), 0) AS OrderQty
FROM   VUItems
GROUP  BY SKU,
          SalesOrderNo
```

Why I need is that I will have a table which will have the quantity on saving this is what I have written to display the Quantity ordered or user eneterd as follows

```
SELECT VU1.*,
       VU1.Quantity - (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(VU2.Quantity), 0) AS OrderQty
                       FROM   VU2
                       WHERE  VU1.SKU = VU2.SKU
                              AND VU1.SalesOrderNo = VU2.SalesOrderNo
                       GROUP  BY SKU) AS orderedQuantity
FROM   VU1
```

with out group by it is displaying `orderedQuantity` as required but with group by it is showing `null`

Comment: can you give us sample records?

Comment: give us the table layout and the records

Comment: By design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102 (and duplicate)

Comment: There will be no records initially

Comment: Assuming `VUItems` is an empty table then this is just the difference between [scalar and vector](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/03/12/fun-with-aggregates.aspx) aggregates.

Comment: Hi `gbn` even I used `count` when I group by a column name it is not displaying `null` without group by it is displaying `null`

Comment: @Learner: count, sum. min, max all behave the same. See my answer on my link above

Comment: Following your edit I don't see the problem. `GROUP  BY SKU` is unnecessary anyway as the `WHERE` clause ensures that at most one `SKU` will match so just leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

The ISNULL needs to be inside the SUM. SUM(NULL) is NULL.