# SQL: Determine the record count for 2 separate filter conditions in the execution of only 1 query

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a BOOK table.

with this structure:

```
create table BOOK (
  AUTHOR varchar2(100),
  TITLE  varchar2(100)
);
```

What I want to do is to check/(or count, count(*) = 1) whether a book with author = 'John Smith' exists, and whether there exists a book authored by 'John Smith' starting with the letter 'T'.

I came up with two SQL statements.

```
select count(1)
  from BOOK
 where AUTHOR = 'John Snow'
   and rownum = 1

select count(1)
  from BOOK
 where AUTHOR = 'John Snow'
   and TITLE like = 'T%'
   and rownum = 1
```

My question is: Is there a way such that I can know whether a book of such criteria exists (I need to know whether there is a book by John Snow and whether he wrote a book with a title starting with the letter 'T') by performing only 1 query? Such that performing this 1 query will be faster than performing the 2 queries from above? Thanks!

Comment: sorry but i don't understand if i return you 1 how do you know is the number of books made by John or the number of books made by john that start with T?

Comment: Such that the query will return 1 row with 2 columns. I column for count of books authored by John Smith and the other the count of books author by John Smith that starts with 'T'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can put the information in two columns:

```
select (case when sum(case when AUTHOR = 'John Snow' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as AuthoredByJohnSnow,
       (case when sum(case when AUTHOR = 'John Snow' and Name like 'T%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as AuthoredByJohnSnowBookT
from Book
```

You can make this more efficient by putting the `AUTHOR = 'John Snow'` in the `where` clause.  This explicitly doesn't do that, so you can easily add more factors in the `select`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    SIGN(count(*)),
    SIGN(count(CASE WHEN TITLE like 'T%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)),
from BOOK
where AUTHOR = 'John Snow';
```

Comment: I assume OP expects `0, 0` when there's no `John Snow`. That complicates things a bit. I was thinking about the same statement but stopped there. Simplest might be to just add a `union 0, 0`. At least, OP only has to provide the criteria once that way but "it aint pretty".

Comment: And shouldn't the count case be changed to max (and have a group by)?

Comment: You will get zero when there is no group by. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2552102/27535. A MAX isn't needed either. This relies on COUNT ignoring NULLs.

Comment: @Ram: I get it now. COUNT with GROUP BY will return one row always as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/2552102/27535

Comment: Wait, isn't this wrong since there is a rownum = 1 condition? Let us say that John Smith has authored two books: 'Rising Sun' and 'The Land of the Rising Sun'. Since the condition is only AUTHOR = 'John Snow' and rownum = 1, once it finds a book authored by John Snow, it will stop fetching more records. So if it stumbles upon 'Rising Sun' first, it would immediately stop, and would only return 1, 0, even though there is a book starting with 'T'.

Comment: @Ram: why I added it back in. For me, rownum is a breaking function. Now I've written it how I normally would. THis does one table scan rather than 2 with subqueries