# if count value is null set it to zero - sql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Can't seem to get this working.  If the count is null I want to set it to zero... else set it to the count.  I am adding multiple counts in another part of my code so I cannot have null values when I do this.

$table = "
    ...

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, IF(count(user_id) = '(null)',0,count(user_id)) as t1count
    FROM screenshot_logs
    GROUP BY user_id) as t_screenshots
        on t_screenshots.user_id = users.user_id
    ...
```

";

Comment: Why would `COUNT(...)` ever return `NULL`? Also remember `NULL` never "equals" anything, not even itself. That's why there's `IS NOT NULL` as a comparison.

Comment: The problem is not in the inline view query; the problem is that references to `t1count` in the outer query can return NULL when the LEFT JOIN operation returns rows where there was no "matching" row found in `t_screenshots`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the outer query, you can replace a `NULL` with a zero using the **`IFNULL()`** function, e.g.

```
SELECT ...
     , IFNULL(v.t1count,0) AS t1count
  FROM ...
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ... AS t1count
                ...
       ) v
    ON ...
```

---

The NULL you are getting returned by the outer query isn't from the inline view query. The NULL is a result of "no match" being found by the `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` operation.

If you are referencing **`v.t1count`** in other expressions in the outer query, you can replace those references with **`NULLIF(v.t1count,0)`** as well.

Comment: @Sajad: presumably, the inline view (derived table) aliased as `v` in the example could contain a `COUNT()` aggregate.  I omitted a COUNT() expression in my answer to highlight an important point...   it's not the COUNT() expression that is returning a NULL value. The issue is that the outer join is causing a NULL to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate COUNT() will always return a value.

Reference: [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result)

Comment: Valid counts are being returned, but if there are none then it is null.  For example, in the example, if there are results it would return say 25, but if there are none I get null which is why I want to set this to 0 in that case.

Answer (score -3):

You don't want to use `=` in there because null is `!=` to everything.  Try the `ifNull()` function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: `IFNULL(count(user_id),0)` doesn't do anything.