# Variable is getting NULL after SUM function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum, scope

I have this code that is part of a stored procedure:

```
SET @_Value = 0
SET @_Cont = 1;

IF(@_FlagControl = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @_Value = SUM(Value)
    FROM Person P 
    INNER JOIN Order O on O.CodPerson = P.CodOrder
    WHERE P.CodPerson = @_CodP
        AND P.CodImp <> 3
        AND P.FlagSituation = 1
        AND @_CodMainPerson = P.CodPerson

    IF(@_Value IS NULL)
        PRINT 'NULL'
    ELSE
        PRINT @_Value
END
```

If I run just this `SELECT` inside the "IF", it returns '0.90'. But when I run this entire query inside a procedure, it is printing NULL.

I don't have idea what is going on.

Comment: What if `@_FlagControl <> 1` and some other statement make @_Value as NULL

Comment: If I put PRINT @_Value just before the SELECt, it prints "0". and jsut after the SELECT it prints nothing.

Comment: The results would depend on the values of `@_CodP` and `@_CodMainPerson`.  It doesn't surprise me that sometimes it prints one value and sometimes another.

Comment: But those are passed by parameters and don't change inside the procedure. I printed the values that are being used (@_CodP and @_CodMainPerson), and ran the same query in another tab with these values, it returns 0.90

Comment: SQL aggregate fucntions, except count, return null if no input rows go into the function. Maybe the conditions in your where clause result in an empty set?

Comment: @Mithrandir, but I printed those @_CodP and @_CodMainPerson values, and used them to run this SELECT in another tab, and it returns 0.9

Comment: then try hard coding `@_CodP` and `@_CodMainPerson` values in select and check

Comment: No idea about SQL Server, but isn't "@_Value = SUM(Value)" a comparison returning TRUE/FALSE? Other dbms do "SELECT SUM(Value) INTO @_Value".

Comment: @jarlh: the assignment is fine, that's valid T-SQL.

Comment: @Mithrandir: Not correct: in this case there is no GROUP BY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102

Answer (score 0):

- You assign `@_Value`
- You check `@_Value`
- You print `@_ValorImposto`

So if `@_Value` is not null, you don't print it...

Edit, it is not this
Therefore, the SELECT has no rows, which when SUMMed gives one row, making `@_Value` NULL

So test and fix the SELECT *in* the stored procedue: print `@_CodP` and `@_CodMainPerson`. SELECT without the SUM.
**Not** in another query with hardcoded values: this proves nothing

Note that SUM without GROUP BY always returns exactly one row.
So `@_Value` will always either either a non-null value or NULL
See [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102) for more

Comment: Sorry, it was worng. I edited the code, now its correct, but the @_value still getting null, that is the problem

Comment: @Mucida: PRINT the actual filter variables, and do a SELECT without the SUM too to see what is really going on.