# I want to assign the number of rows to "variable"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to assign the total number of rows to a variable named **"@row_count"**.

```
DECLARE @row_count int
SET @row_count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information
```

I know. I'm doing **wrong**. But I haven't found anything on how to do it.

---

I want to do something like that:

```
CREATE PROC add_person
(
    @id tinyint,
    @name nvarchar(max),
    @surname nvarchar(max),
    @salary int,
    @job nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO information
    VALUES(@id,@name,@surname,@salary,@job)
END

DECLARE @row_count nvarchar(max)
SET @row_count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information

BEGIN TRAN
add_person 34,'asdf','asdf',3000,'asdf'
IF @row_count > 33
    ROLLBACK TRAN
ELSE
    COMMIT TRAN
GO;
```

**My goal:** to prevent the addition of new people if the number of people exceeds thirty-four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a variable in this case. You can solve it without using a variable. You can check the result of the query directly on the `IF` like the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN

EXEC add_person 34,'asdf','asdf',3000,'asdf'

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information) > 33
    ROLLBACK TRAN
ELSE
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

In case you need to assign the result of `COUNT(*)` into a variable have a look at the answers here or have a look at the following question on StackOverflow:

- [Saving a select count(*) value to an integer (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403012/saving-a-select-count-value-to-an-integer-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
DECLARE @row_count int;
SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*) FROM information;
```

Comment: Error *Must declare the scalar variable "@row_count".*

Comment: @Codeblogger isn't that obvious. Anyways see edit in answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SELECT` or a sub query:

```
SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*)
FROM information;
--or
SET @row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information);
```